# Does Java have a super()-like keyword that executes a method with the same signature as the caller on an object that's not in the inheritance tree?

Tags: java

In order to separate presentation concerns from data concerns when working with JAXB and Jackson annotations, I use the below pattern for every one of my views (simplified example with some reflection weirdness that is not the focus of this question). The reason this is defined like this with reflection etc is because this code is part of a Spring REST API. Spring only calls parameterless constructors, and getter/setters during conversion of an XML/JSON string to an object, so I need to ensure that everything related to instantiation occurs in such a method.

XmlBaseView:

```
public abstract class XmlBaseView<V extends BaseView> {


    protected V view;

    /**
     * Constructor during unmarshalling (from xml/json to java objects).
     */
    public XmlBaseView() {
        super();
        setNewView();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate a new View object before the unmarshalling process.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void setNewView() {
        Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        Type type = ((java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Class<V> clazz = (Class<V>) type;
        Constructor<V> viewConstructor = null;
        try {
            viewConstructor = clazz.getConstructor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InternalServerException("XmlBaseView: Exception when trying to get the constructor from the concrete view class.", e);
        }
        V view = null;
        try {
            view = viewConstructor.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InternalServerException("XmlBaseView: Exception when trying to instantiate the concrete view class.", e);
        }
        setView(view);
    }

    /**
     * @return the view
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    public V getView() {
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * @param view the view to set
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    public void setView(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }


}
```

XmlExampleView:

```
public class XmlExampleView extends XmlBaseView<ExampleView> {


    public XmlExampleView() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name.
     *
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return view.getName();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name.
     *
     * @param name the name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.view.setName(name);
    }

    // up to 30 more getters and setters
}
```

XmlExampleView:

```
public class UserGroupView extends BaseView {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Returns the name.
     *
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name.
     *
     * @param name the name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Up to 30 more getters and setters.
}
```

The problem I have right now is that I can sometimes have up to 30 or 40 getters and setters in a newly created XmlFooView or XmlBarView that I need manually update so they point to the setter with the exact same signature in the contained FooView. It's slow, tiresome, and boring, but if it isn't done properly, I end up with getters or setters in the XmlFooView that point to the wrong getter or setter in the FooView.

The question I have: For classes that use inheritance, there is a concept of super() or super.doSomething() that allows for code reuse so you can define everything in the same place. Is there something comparable I can use my XmlExampleView on my getters and setters that will call the method with the same signature in a class of choosing at compile time? Something like `view.super()` or `super(view)`? What I'm ideally hoping for is something that will help me with not having to manually update the getters and setters each time I create a new class inheriting from XmlBaseView(), something I can copy-paste from each setter to the next without having to update it.

Comment: you mean "can Java magically know which method of which class I want it to by having a similar signature as the method in which I want it to be called"? No.

Comment: @Stultuske no, more like something like `view.super()`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... with `view.` you can already access methods declared both in the super class or in the child class. You don't need `view.super` to access methods from the base class.

Comment: @Nzall sure, that technique is called "calling an instance method through an instance of the class". So, as long as you have an instance called view, and it is an instance of the class of which you want to call the super() method (of course it'll need another name), that's indeed possible, though not very dynamic

Comment: Try to explain what you want to achieve without reinventing Java in your head :-) In this case it will be easier to help you. FYI what you do in XmlBaseView class is very dirty - XmlBaseView instance is of BaseView type, you don't need to store BaseView instance inside of it. It doesn't relate to OOP.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev NO, XmlBaseView instance CONTAINS a single object of type V that extends BaseView. It does NOT extend BaseView itself.

Comment: @Stultuske I've slightly updated my question. Essentially, I'm wondering if there's a Java construct I can copy-paste into all my getters and setters that will execute a function with the same method signature as the calling code in an object defined at compile-time.

Comment: not sure if it's 100% what you mean, but have you considered aop?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve tbh. Something about views delegating getter and setter calls to other views, but it's not clear at all to me what it is that's being viewed or even what a "view" is in this context (sounds like an xml representation for some object). I'd suggest just creating individual data classes for each and mappers to transfer between them. Mapstruct does this automatically for properties of the same name.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, then the "high level" goal is to avoid having XML/JSON/whatever annotations in your "core" classes. That's fine (and I also don't like to have this sort of annotations - the way how a class may be serialized to XML/JSON should not be "part" of the class itself, for an awful lot of reasons). And you tried to achieve this goal using the `Xml*`-"wrapper" classes and delegation. Now, the question is how to automate this delegation, is that correct? If this is the case, I cannot think of a solution that directly works with the given `Xml*` classes. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd:) One could consider defining interfaces and using Dynamic Proxy Classes, or (other, custom) reflection trickery, or some sort of code generators, or custom serializers/deserializers (that's what I usually do with Jackson - it's a bit cumbersome, but avoids having the Jackson annotations in the core classes. I don't know whether this is sensibly possible with JAXB, though...).

Comment: @Marco13 Do you think you could make a full answer out of those 2 comments, giving some extra clarifications on the alternative considerations that might be usable alternatively? And you've hit the nail on the head when it comes to the high level goal. The problem is that there's not just a REST API, there's also a Struts2 GUI, but also a number of related daemons. We do not want to have annotations that are only needed by the REST API for serialization in views used by the Daemons, because that would complicate the containerization we employ for these for no good reason.